# Is Microsoft pushing Spark or Razor for the future view engine for ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am planning to learn ASP.NET MVC soon. I wanted to get a clear picture of which view engine should I concentrate on, Spark or Razor? Which one is Microsoft putting more energy into?

Comment: Should your question really have been WebForms ViewEngine or Razor ViewEngine?

Comment: I think I got confused somewhere when I read that MS hired Spark's developer.

Comment: They did hire him, they did not buy his IP (Spark)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Spark](http://sparkviewengine.com/) has not been developed by Microsoft and I wouldn't say that they have/intend to put much energy on it. On the other hand Razor is Microsoft child and if you want an MS supported view engine go for it.

Comment: The guy who wrote Spark currently works for Microsoft in the ASP.NET group, but he joined after creating Spark and still maintains it as a seperate project

Answer (score 10):

Tony, I'm one of the developers on the ASP.NET MVC team. Here are some thoughts:

We developed Razor because we felt that the Aspx view engine had a number of shortcomings and we felt that we could do a lot better (and I do hope that people will agree that the result is a lot better). We would recommend Razor to anyone starting a new MVC 3 application. Anyone with an existing MVC 2 application and a heavy investment in the WebForms view engine will have to do their own cost/benefit analysis and decide if they want to switch.

Both view engines (Razor and Aspx) will continue to be supported (we are not planning on deprecating WebForms) and we will make sure that existing APIs as well as anything new that we add continue to work in both. That said, it might not always be possible to keep the feature set of each view engine at parity (for example, the `@model` keyword has no direct analouge in WebForms).

Spark is a 3rd-party component and it remains independent from Microsoft (regardless of the fact that its creator, Louis DeJardin is now employeed here). As such we are not currently contributing any code to it (since we've had our hands quite full with Razor). We are, however, fully committed to exposing all the necessary APIs and extensions points to support 3rd-party view engines. For example, in MVC 3 we have made improvements to the New Project and Add View dialogs to make it easier for the Spark (or any other view engine such as NHaml) developers or community to plug Spark into the built in MVC tooling experience.

Ultimately all options are valid (though in [my personal opinion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019740/does-razor-syntax-provide-a-compelling-advantage-in-ui-markup/4021282#4021282) the Aspx view engine is slightly *less* valid :) and it's up to you to find the one that best fits your needs.

Comment: Invariably, the aspx engine would fall, due to it's own nature, or it would be transformed into something else, either removing old support or becoming way too complex to maintain. Creating an engine anew was the most toughtfull way, I think, to help all the developers, keeping support to technologies from yore.

Comment: I believe that te question relates to both template languages, Spark and Razor, and, sometimes, we've to expose our opnion, veiled from eyes of the viewer, not directly showing our real opinion, either minding the whole company community friendly position, either avoiding a helpless fight. But we fully unaderstood you. And your point. And yes, razor is awesome. And spark too. And Aspx, was fine while it lasted. thank you for making my work swell again.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stay w/ Microsoft-supported view engines, then your options are Razor or WebForms.  I prefer Razor of the two.  Spark is arguably a better view engine than Razor is right now (depending on your sense of style), but as Darin pointed out it's not an MS product, so they're not putting energy into it that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 2):

**Razor** is the best option if you want to minimize the amount of code in your view and if you like the syntax.

**WebForms** is good if you have a lot of experience with traditional ASP.NET and like the idea of having a code behind.

**Spark** is not supported or written by Microsoft.

For me, I use Razor as I like the syntax and I find my views a lot cleaner. Sure it's more verbose than *haml*, but at the same time it still is *valid* looking HTML and most web developers will pick it up naturally.

Comment: "Razor is the best option if you want to minimize the amount of code in your view",  A  very subjective statement. Take a look at Spark Bindings then come back and tell me if you feel the same way. http://sparkviewengine.com/documentation/bindings

Comment: I have used Spark. My comparison was primarily on Razor vs. WebForms as the question was posed as supported by Microsoft and Spark is not being officially supported. All things being equal, I prefer HAML to everything else.