# How can I change this ASP syntax to Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How can I convert this to ASP.NET?

Or how can I convert ASP to Razor, what will I add or remove and what are the things to remember while converting ASP to Razor or reverse.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<PopulatingDDLusingEF.ViewModels.IndexViewModel>" %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<PopulatingDDLusingEF.ViewModels.IndexViewModel>" %>
```

In **Razor** you should use `@Model` keyword

```
@model PopulatingDDLusingEF.ViewModels.IndexViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Result";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Site.Master";   
}
```

**This is an example how to convert ASP syntax to razor syntax which i got from Marcind's [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019740/does-razor-syntax-provide-a-compelling-advantage-in-ui-markup/4021282#4021282)**

```
<% if(someCondition) { %>
  <ol>
  <% foreach(var item in Model) { %>
     <li><%: item.ToString() %></li>
  <% } %>
  </ol>
<% } %>

Can be expressed as follows in Razor:

@if(someCondition) {
   <ol>
   @foreach(var item in Model) {
      <li>@item.ToString()</li>
   }
   </ol>
}
```

**Also check [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx) for a quick useful Razor reference**

Comment: Thanks @ssilas777!  
Can you give me some good website/blogs that gives step by step tutorial learning MVC razor?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/razor_intro.asp - For beginner this will do, i wouldn't recommend though

Comment: I had been in W3Schools.com but I need some advancement, anyway Thanks again.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/basics/2-introduction-to-asp-net-web-programming-using-the-razor-syntax - Check this too