# What is transition character?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Somewhere I read ASPX view engine has 21 transition characters where as Razor view engine has  3 transition characters. What does this transition character mean ? What are they in Razor & ASPX view engine?

Comment: See [Does Razor syntax provide a compelling advantage in UI markup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019740/does-razor-syntax-provide-a-compelling-advantage-in-ui-markup). They mean characters like `@` for `@Model.Propert` in Razor and `<%%>` in ASPX.

Comment: So, are the 3 transition characters in razor @, @: & @*....*@??

Answer (score 0):

I guess they mean with 'transition character' a character that indicates the transition from the render engine to the code engine.

Those symbols, like `@` in Razor, indicates that the following is a code segment, and that it should be interpreted by the compiler, rather than the view render engine.

Answer (score 0):

The key transition character in Razor is the “at” sign (@). This character is used to switch from markup to code and sometimes again back to markup.

Source:
http://www.ecanarys.com/blog-entry/razor-view-engine-mvc

Comment: In ASPX, transition characters are "<%:"